# css define default font size per page

Tags: css

I just realized that two webpages produce different font sizes with the same rem value. I thought that rem is based on the browser wide default font size.
Is it possible to set the base value for 1 rem on a per page basis rather than browser wide? Or can the css/html define the default font size?

Answer (score 1):

You should define the font size for the `body` tag e.g. `16px`

```
body {
  font-size: 16px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you apply a different class to `body` on each page, you can use that as a selector and set different basic font-sizes, like

```
body.start {
  font-size: 16px;
}
body.portfolio {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

Wordpress  for example applies different classes to `body` automatically.

Answer (score 0):

the 1 rem is by default 16px for most browsers 
if you want to make sure you can always do it by your self just like this:

```
html {
 font-size: 16px;
}
```